# JQGrid displayed over container (div with overflow:auto) in IE6/7

Tags: jqgrid

I'm loading a JQGrid dynamically (using Jquery's load function).

The grid is loaded inside a div that has the overflow:auto property, the idea is that if the grid is too wide, the div will display scrollbars.

This approach works just fine with IE8, FF3, Chrome, but in IE6 and IE7 the grid is displayed over the container div, even though the div displays the scroll bars, it doesn't hide the grid.

Here: http://www.twitpic.com/nj2xe  you can see the two different results, the first one is with IE6, and the second one (expected) with IE8.

Any idea of how to overcome this?

Comment: Did you find a resolution for this issue?  We are seeing a similar issue and seeking advice.

Answer (score 0):

I placed the jqGrid inside of a table (with one row and cell) and that seems to help with some layout problems I was having.  Maybe it would help you also.